# I have an issue related to AJAX

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

> I need to get the value after it is created, just below the section "NEW"

Below is the image I intended to do, and after the data was created I wanted it right there

[image: uesiton]

phrases_term_controller.rb

```
class PhrasesTermsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_term

  def new
    @phrases_term = PhrasesTerm.new
  end

  def create
    @phrases_term = @term.phrases_terms.new(phrases_term_params)
    if @phrases_term.save
      redirect_to term_phrases_term_path(@term, @phrases_term), notice: "Phrases_Term was successfully created"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @phrases_term = PhrasesTerm.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def phrases_term_params
    params.require(:phrases_term).permit(:term_id, :phrase_id)
  end

  def set_term
    @term = Term.find(params[:term_id])
  end
end
```

View
phrases_term

new.html.erb

```
<h1><%= I18n.t("pages.phrases_term.new.title") %></h1>
<%= render 'form', phrases_term: @phrases_term %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :phrases_term, url: term_phrases_terms_path, local: true do |form| %>
  <% if phrases_term.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(phrases_term.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this phrase from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% phrases_term.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :term_id %> :
    <%= form.number_field :id %>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Phrase</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a><%= form.select :phrase_id, Phrase.all.collect { |p| [ p.id ] }, include_blank: true %></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Term:

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: term, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if term.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(term.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this term from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% term.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :word %>
    <%= form.text_field :word %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :meaning %>
    <%= form.text_field :meaning %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :reading %>
    <%= form.text_field :reading %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure I have provided all the necessary information, if I want to add some more information, please comment below. ---Thank You.----

Comment: I can't see the text field labeled `Term` in your `_form.html.erb`. What should it do?

Comment: sorry i added the above ...

Comment: Do you want to let the users submit one term at a time, or do you want them to submit a batch of terms? If you want them to submit a batch, do you want them to see the terms they just typed in, or all the terms they've ever submitted, or both?

Comment: yes i  want them to submit a batch of terms? and i want them to submit a batch,  both.

Comment: I'm still waiting for your answer ...